# Is the set of all characteristic functions on a set A equivalent to its power set P(A)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Recently I studied something known as characteristic function (Indicator function). After going through it deeply I want know if the set of all characteristic functions on A will be equivalent to its power set P(A)?

Comment: What do you mean by similar ? Is your set $A$ fintie ? infinite ?

Comment: I will be glad if you answer the question in both the cases...

Comment: You don't mean *similar*. What you mean is *equivalent*

Answer (score 2):

A characteristic function on $A$ is a function of domain $A$ and range $\subseteq\{0,\,1\}$. Matching such a function $\varphi$ with $\{x\in A|\varphi(x)=1\}$ bijects the characteristic functions on $A$ with the subsets of $A$ (and so does using $\{x\in A|\varphi(x)=0\}$, but that's a bit confusing).